# pydantic validation errors for a response model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

This is my function to create user in an API made with fastapi:

```
@router.post("/", response_model=schemas.UserResponse)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate):
    conn, cursor = get_db()
    query = """SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_email = %s;"""
    value = (user.email,)
    cursor.execute(query, value)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    if row is not None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, detail=f"This 
    email already exists")

    # Create the hash of the user password
    hashed_password = utils.hash(user.password)
    user.password = hashed_password

    # Create the user
    conn, cursor = get_db()
    query = """INSERT INTO users (u_fname, u_email, u_password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) 
    RETURNING *;"""
    values = (user.first_name, user.email, user.password)
    cursor.execute(query, values)
    new_user = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    
    return new_user
```

and these are the pydantic models involved:

```
class UserBase(BaseModel):
    first_name: constr(min_length=1)
    email: EmailStr


class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str


class UserResponse(UserBase):
    created_at: datetime

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

When I call the API to create user, this is indeed created in the database, but I have got the following error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 3 validation errors for UserResponse
response -> first_name
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> email
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> created_at
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

What is happening here? Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried to check what `new_user` actually _is_ in that function and what its `type` is? Because the route needs a specific type to be returned to be able to parse it into a `UserResponse` object and I doubt `cursor.fetchone()` returns something appropriate.

Comment: Hi Daniil. The type of new_user is <class 'psycopg2.extras.RealDictRow'>. I am using RealDictCursor from psycopg2.extras.

Comment: Still, have you checked that your [`RealDictRow`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.RealDictRow) instance actually contains those keys? I.e. `first_name`, `email` and `created_at`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Now checked. False for the three of them! Everything clear now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the error because `cursor.fetchone()` return a tuple representing a row in the users table but you need to return an instance of your `schemas.UserResponse` model.

Try returning something like that :

```
return schemas.UserResponse(

    first_name=new_user[1],
    email=new_user[2],
    created_at=new_user[3]
)
```

Comment: Almost. Converting to `UserResponse` is the job of `response_model=schemas.UserResponse` in the route decorator. But that would require a dictionary or an object with the same attributes (for ORM mode) to be returned. Definitely not a tuple.

Comment: Hi nox. It doesn't work